# How to change the link text in the `\gls{label}` command?

Tags: hyperref, cross-referencing, glossaries, hyperlink

I am using the `glossaries` package to create a glossary in my thesis. And I would like to be able to change the link text in the command `\gls{<label>}`.

That is I'd like to be able to refer to the very same entry in the glossary with customizable link text of the hyperlink created by `\gls{<label>}`.

The reason is that there are circumstances (other than the plural form of a word I would like to appear in the glossary) which forces me to show different text for the same glossary entry.

Thank you very much in advance!

Answer (score 2):

Silly me! I've found the answer in the manual:

> It is `\glslink{label}{my-text}`

works like a charme!